# MySQL SELECT and GROUPING

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL (mySQL) and I am trying to create a query that will populate a google chart specifically
The result should look something like this:

```
      ['group_name', 'Open_tickets_count', 'closed_tickets_count'],
      ['Team A',     10,                 400],
      ['Team B',     30,                 460],
      ['Team C',     66,                1120],
      ['Team D',      5,                 540]
```

I have a tickets table that includes the following fields: id ticket_status group_name.
A few things:

1. In this example I only have two statuses, but the number of 
       statuses is actually variable
2. The number of teams is also variable
3. the actual group_names and tickets_statuses are ids to other 
       tables in my real table. (but I can figure out how to substitute)

I have tried everything my imagination and limited knowledge allows and got not even near to achieve this. Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

[Adding sample table structures (only relevant fields)]

```
Table: tickets
'id', 'int(10)'
'ticket_status_id', 'int(10)' 
'ticket_group_id', 'int(10)'

Table: status
'id', 'int(10)'
'name', 'varchar(250)'

Table: groups
'id', 'int(10)'
'name', 'varchar(250)'
```

Comment: What do you mean "the number of statuses is variable"?

Comment: *...the actual group_names and tickets_statuses are ids to other 
    tables in my real table.* Please show structures and sample data for these tables

Comment: Hi Matt, the number of statuses is not limited to Open and Closed, but  includes for example "Work in Progress" or "awaiting verification of fix" .. it is actually a separate table. Hope this makes sense..

Comment: Why don't you write something like this :
    
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    <?php 
        while($row=mysql_fecth_assoc($data)){
         echo "['group_name','open_tickets_count','closed_tickets_count],
['".$row['group_name."','".$row['open_tickets_count."','".$row['closed_tickets_count']."']
        } ?>)

Comment: thank you Sahin but, this is not php. (its a query/template interface that only accepts plain SQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal you need to use conditional `SUM()` with `GROUP BY` and dynamic SQL (`PREPARE`, `EXECUTE`).

Your base script might look like this

```sql
SET @sql = '';
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(CASE WHEN t.ticket_status = ''',
      id,
      ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `',
      name, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  status;

SET @sql = CONCAT
('SELECT g.name, ', @sql, ' 
    FROM tickets t JOIN status s
      ON t.ticket_status = s.id JOIN groups g
      ON t.ticket_group_id = g.id 
   GROUP BY t.ticket_group_id,  g.name'
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5107/3)** demo.

Comment: Wow, that seems to do it. But I got a lot of research to do before I fully understand it. It will keep me entertained for awhile. I really appreciate the time you spent on this. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Lets go with your assumptions.

You can try something like

```
SELECT  group_name,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ts.status = 'OPEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Open_tickets_count
        SUM(CASE WHEN ts.status = 'CLOSED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) closed_tickets_count
FROM    tickets t INNER JOIN
        ticket_statusses ts ON  t.ticket_status = ts.id
GROUP BY    group_name
```

You would have to add new columns for different statusses.

Comment: Thank you, this give me some starting point but I am not sure it actually solves the problem. because in your query only two statuses are taken into consideration. the actual statuses comes from a table and can be any number. I have added some table structure to the original post. Thank you again for your help. I will experiment with this.